# What is tripping me up on SSE in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, server-sent-events

I have successfully implemented the trivial example documented [here](https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/streaming-data-with-asp-net-web-api-and-pushcontentstream/), which demonstrates how to transmit server-sent events to a client, but I'm having difficulty going beyond the example.

The server I wrote (IIS/ASP.Net/C#/Web API 2) can handle multiple instances of a game being played at once. Each game has a unique handle.

The client provides the UI for the game. It makes an API request to start a game and is given a handle in the response. It then calls the Subscribe method, passing the handle. As in the example, it uses PushStreamContent to do so. My implementation looks like this;

```
  private Game mGame;
  private static readonly ConcurrentBag<Tuple<Game, StreamWriter>> mscolListenerStreams;

  // GET: api/v1.0/subscription/{gameId:int}
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("{gameId:int}")]
  public HttpResponseMessage Subscribe(int gameId) {

     mGame = Game.GetGame(gameId);
     if (mGame is null) {
        return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Unknown GameId");
     }

     mGame.GameEvent += game_Event; // Assign an event handler to follow game events.

     HttpResponseMessage response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     response.Content = new PushStreamContent(
        (a, b, c) => { this.OnStreamAvailable(a, b, c); },
        "text/event-stream");
     return response;

  }
```

Instead of just saving off the stream as in the example, I need to tie a stream to a game. I do that like this:

```
  private void OnStreamAvailable(Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context) {

     mscolListenerStreams.Add(new Tuple<Game, StreamWriter>(mGame, new StreamWriter(stream)));

  }
```

Instead of the timer event in the example, I use the game event handler to send messages to the relevant streams:

```
  private async static void game_Event(Game game, EventId eventId, int index) {

     foreach (Tuple<Game, StreamWriter> tuple in mscolListenerStreams) {
        if (!object.ReferenceEquals(tuple.Item1, game)){
           continue;
        }
        try {
           await tuple.Item2.WriteAsync($"event:Game\ndata:{game.Id}/{eventId}/{index}\n\n");
           await tuple.Item2.FlushAsync();
        }
        catch {
           Tuple<Game, StreamWriter> ignore;
           if (mscolListenerStreams.TryTake(out ignore)) {
              ignore.Item2.Dispose();
           }
        }
     }

  }
```

As soon as the game fires an event (instead of the timer that's in the example), the clients locks up and stop receiving server messages or they get CORS errors whenever they try to make subsequent API calls. (The client domain is allowed.) The timer still works.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr) and have decided to roll your own server sent events?

Comment: Yes. I want to understand the underlying technology. That’s the real purpose of the app.

Comment: Well if it's just for learning purposes, why did you pick Server Sent Events? Why not web sockets? That's still low level, while still having context in the wider world.

Comment: That’s also on the list.